# How can I scan QR code and get the PDF stored in it iOS app

Tags: ios, swift3

Tried many things. But still I am not able to retrieve the stored PDF from a QR code. When I scan the code, I am getting the url output.

```
 func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection:   AVCaptureConnection!) {
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            messageLabel.text = "No barcode/QR code is detected"
            return
        }
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as!     AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if supportedBarCodes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
//        if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What were you expecting? If you have the url just get the data from it.

Comment: `I am getting the url output.` does it mean you are getting the url of the file stored in document directory of iPhone?

Comment: i got it right.. sorry guys. there was an error with my webview. thank you